# fail2Ban apache-noscript line missed

Tags: fail2ban

I'm trying, without success, to ban this line using `fail2ban-regex` :

```
root@XXXX:/etc/fail2ban#fail2ban-regex '[Mon Jun 22 09:55:16.780767 2015] [:error] [pid 1962] [client 1.2.3.4:38909] script '/var/html/abc.php' not found or unable to stat' filter.d/apache-noscript.conf
```

using the original `failregex` in the `apache-noscript`

```
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s ((AH001(28|30): )?File does not exist|(AH01264: )?script not found or unable to stat): /\S*(\.php|\.a$
            ^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat\s*$
```

the result is line 'missed' (i was waiting for line 'matched' )

```
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
|- Missed line(s):
|  [Mon Jun 22 09:55:16.780767 2015] [:error] [pid 1962] [client 1.2.3.4:38909] script /var/html/abc.php not found or unable to stat
```

Please do you know the `The_good_failregex` to match this line (as like in std log) ?  `(Fail2Ban v0.8.11  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu))` :

```
fail2ban-regex '[Mon Jun 22 09:55:16.780767 2015] [:error] [pid 1962] [client 1.2.3.4:38909] script '/var/html/abc.php' not found or unable to stat' The_good_failregex
```

Many Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be version issue.

Fail2Ban v0.8.11 was currently used,
need to be be updated to v0.8.12 (:? before 'error' ...)

> _apache_error_client = [[^]]*] [(:?error|\S+:\S+)]( [pid \d+(:\S+ \d+)?])? [client (:\d{1,5})

Thanks.